# Non-static loop limit exceeded in Xilinx

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I have this code in VHDL:

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use ieee.NUMERIC_STD.all;

entity Div is 
    Port ( Ain   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);   
    Bin   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);   
    Q   : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);   
    R   : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0)    
    Rez : out std_logic_vector(13 downto 0));   
end Div;

architecture Behavioral of Div is

begin
  Proc1 : process (Ain, Bin) is 
  variable cnt   : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0); 
  variable Atemp : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0); 
  begin 
      if (Ain < Bin) then     
          cnt   := "0000000";     
          Atemp := Ain;   
      elsif (Ain = Bin) then    
          cnt := "0000001";     
          Atemp := (others => '0');    
      elsif (Ain > Bin) then     
          cnt   := "0000001";     
          Atemp := (Ain - Bin);     
          while (Atemp >= Bin) loop       
               Atemp := (Atemp - Bin);       
               cnt   := cnt + "0000001";     
          end loop;   
      end if;

      Q <= cnt;   
      R <= Atemp;
      Rez <= "0000000" & cnt;

      end process Proc1;

end Behavioral;
```

and when I synt in Xilinx, I have this error message

> Non-static loop limit exceeded

at that while loop.

Comment: If your logic synthesiser could work out how to synthesise this, it would synthesise a big chunk of combinational logic. If a combinational divider is what you want, why not just synthesise the `/` operator?

Comment: What does this loop do when Bin = 0?

Answer (score 0):

When VHDL is synthesised, the synth tool needs to unwrap your loop to create a circuit. Because it has no idea what the Atemp or Bin are, other than they are 7 bit integers, it has to assume that Atemp and Bin could be static forever, and hence the loop never unrolls.

The problem with your code is that you used a while loop. Your HDL needs to describe a circuit, and a while loop generally doesn't. Instead of using a while loop, consider using a clock in your process and incrementing the counter by 1 on each clock. Circuits have no knowledge of time without a clock.